# How to override mouseLeave event using mouseClick event

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if anyone could help me out on button effect i am working on for windows c# forum.

So I have two similar image, one with a background glow and another without, to create a button.
I am using `mouseEnter(glow)` and `mouseLeave(normal)` to give an effect to a button which works fine.

I have 8 different buttons on the same form, for which there is different images.

I want the mouseEnter event to continue after I mouseclick the button i.e the glow effect,  but I am not able to get a right solution. 
And when a different(next) button is clicked the button that was glowing should go back to normal.

Was wondering if anyone would be able to point me towards right direction, did a bit of search online haven't been able to come up with a solution.

```
private void btnSong1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.btnSong1.BackgroundImage = 
        ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.satisfactionH));
}

private void btnSong1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.btnSong1.BackgroundImage = 
        ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.satisfaction));
}

private void btnSong1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nowPlaying1.Visible = Enabled;
    nowPlaying2.Visible = false;
    nowPlaying5.Visible = false;

    this.btnSong1.BackgroundImage = 
        ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.satisfactionH));

    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = 
        @"C:\MediaFile\music\ArethaFranklin\(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction.mp3";
}

private void btnSong2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.btnSong1.BackgroundImage = 
        ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.satisfaction));
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"C:\MediaFile\music\ArethaFranklin\Come To Me.mp3";
    nowPlaying1.Visible = false;
    nowPlaying2.Visible = Enabled;
    nowPlaying5.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: what code have you thus far can you show what you have so that we can get a more visual idea based on the existing code..?

Comment: `i am working on for windows c# forum`.  Do you mean "windows forms"?

Comment: Yeha tell us over wich plataform (windows forms or web) are you developping, i suspect you're over the web because you mention a forum.

Comment: yes it is windows forms.

Comment: I just posed the code. Sorry my first time posting here. Was not expecting such a fast respond.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using your own buttonClass. I did a quick demo `GlowingButton`. Plays a given songUrl on click, glows on mouse enter and resets background on leave or on click.

```
// don't forget: using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class GlowingButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand,
                                             StringBuilder strReturn,
                                             int iReturnLength,
                                             IntPtr hwndCallback);

    public string SongURL { get; set; }
    public GlowingButton() : base()
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Winforms_Demo.Properties.Resources.bg;
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        this.BackgroundImage = Winforms_Demo.Properties.Resources.bgGlow;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        this.BackgroundImage = Winforms_Demo.Properties.Resources.bg;
    }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        this.BackgroundImage = Winforms_Demo.Properties.Resources.bg;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SongURL))
        {
            mciSendString("open \"" + SongURL + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            mciSendString("play MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Within your form all you have to do is set a **songUrl** for **each glowingButton** (via designer or within your source)!

Comment: Thank you Pilgerstorfer Franz, it does work with only one button but I have 8 different button on my form. Each button is related to different songs. When i click next button I want the glow effect on first button (or whichever button) is glowing to go back to normal.

Comment: rewrote my answer as of given details - pls have a look